# Close bootstrap dropdown menu aftering clicking on ipad

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried several ways to close the dropdown but I cannot figure it out.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role='menu'>
                <li><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2">section2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear

Comment: if you open your dropdown and then click anyware outside the dropdown or on one of the items it will close directly

Comment: It doesn't close after click on ipad,iphone. it's still open after I click on it.

Comment: you haven't mensioned it that it was on mobile devices, please add this in your question

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is simpler than you think. I fixed my problem by changing the max width that it set to collapse into the ipad size from

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
```

to

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"`

this should close your Dropdown by clicking (or touching) one of the links.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li data-target=".dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
                <li data-target=".dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#section2">section2</a></li>
                <li data-target=".dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```